# Laravel 5.2 project has started reporting "Trying to get propert of non-object"

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I have had this app developed for over two years, and nothing has changed on it. But all of a sudden this week, it started throwing out this error.

> Trying to get property 'conversation_interlocutors' of non-object
>   at HandleExceptions->handleError('8', 'Trying to get property 'conversation_interlocutors' of non-object', '/home/admin/web/365onlinework.com/public_html/app/Services/MessageService.php', '47', array('collection' => object(WebsiteUser))) in MessageService.php line 47

So, the script in questions is here.

```
 public function getConversations()
    {
        $websites = Website::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();

        $conversations = collect();

        foreach ($websites as $website) {
            if (auth()->user()->can('view', $website)) {

                $this->tenant->connect($website);

                $collections = $website->managed_users()
                    ->with(['user.conversation_interlocutors' => function ($query) {
                        $query
                            ->select('id', 'read', 'initiatorId', 'interlocutorId')
                            ->where('read', 0)
                            ->orWhere('read', 1)
                            ->has('initiator')
                            ->has('interlocutor')
                            ->has('messages')
                            ->with(['flagged', 'interlocutor.website',
                                'initiator' => function ($i) {
                                    $i->select('id', 'username');
                                }])
                            ->withCount('messages');
                    }])->get();

                $filtered = $collections->filter(function ($collection) {
                    return $collection->user->conversation_interlocutors;
                });

                foreach ($filtered as $filter) {
                    $conversations->push($filter->user->conversation_interlocutors);
                }
            }
        }

        $conversations = $conversations->flatten()->sortBy('lastMessageTimestamp')->values();
        return $conversations;
    }
```

Line 47 is:

```
 return $collection->user->conversation_interlocutors;
```

I tried to do an if isset to check if it's nulled and it goes through, but then it shows nothing on the output at all.  Normally it shows the list of conversations.

As well we already do a check if it has a value while doing the query, this has been running for a long time already, and I am not sure what is causing the error.

Comment: `$collection->user->conversation_interlocutors;` You're assuming that `$collection->user` is a `User`, when it could be `null`. Add some constraints to your query, like `->has("user")`, or check for `$collection->user` before trying to access another property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because `$collection->user` is `null`. To fix it use this code:

```
$collection->user->conversation_interlocutors ?? null;
```

or

```
!empty($collection->user->conversation_interlocutors) 
    ? $collection->user->conversation_interlocutors 
    : null;
```

Comment: Note the first option (null-coalescing) requires PHP7 and there's a good chance if they are running Laravel 5.2, they aren't running PHP7.

Comment: Thanks this fixed it.